# Wait for application window to open before continuing

Tags: swift, macos

I want to open an application in Swift and wait for the application window to open before continuing.

I'm opening the application using:

```
func openApp(appPath: String, callback: @escaping (NSRunningApplication) -> Void) {
    let conf = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration();
    NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(
        at: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: appPath),
        configuration: conf
    ) { app, err in
        callback(app!)
    }
}

// relevant code inside another function:
if (app == nil) 
    guard let appPath = NSWorkspace.shared.absolutePathForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: bundleId) else { throw MyError.runtimeError("no app path")}
    do {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
            
            
        try app = NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(at: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: appPath), options: [], configuration: [:])
            
        group.enter()

        openApp(appPath: appPath) { (newApp) in
            app = newApp;
            group.leave();
        }
            
        group.wait();
            
    } catch {
        throw MyError.runtimeError("failed to launch");
    }
}
```

at a later stage I need the windows of that application, which I get using:

```
extension AXUIElement {

    func getAttribute<T>(key: String) -> T {
        var ptr: AnyObject?
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(self, "AX\(key)" as CFString, &ptr)
        if key == "Size" ||  key == "Position" {
            let val = ptr as! AXValue
            return val.toValue()
        }
        return ptr as! T
    }

    func setAttribute<T: AnyObject>(key: String, value: T) {
        AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(self, "AX\(key)" as CFString, value)
    }
}

let axApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app!.processIdentifier)
let windows: [AXUIElement] = axApp.getAttribute(key: kAXWindowsAttribute) as [AXUIElement];
```

but when the application launches, this code is executed before an actual window is opened. So I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7fff8e6b2cd8) to 'Swift.Array<__C.AXUIElementRef>' (0x7fff8e6b2c78).
```

How can I wait for the window to open before executing the code to get the window instance

Comment: Tip: check the result of `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` and `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue`.

Comment: @Willeke you mean the return value of both functions?

Comment: Yes, don't you want to know if the result is `kAXErrorSuccess`?

Comment: Is the window always opened automatically after startup?

Comment: The windows opens when I run `NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication`, but the code afterwards doesn't wait for the actual window to open. I want to wait for that window so I can resize it

Comment: Have you tried `NSWorkspace.didLaunchApplicationNotification` or `openApplication(at:configuration:completionHandler:)`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem recently. I want to resize window and relocate window position after open application. Here is my solution in Swift 5.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(fileURLs,
                            withApplicationAt: appUrl,
                            configuration: config) { runningApp, error in
        
        guard error == nil else { return }
        
        while true {

            //wait for application actual finished launch
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
            
            guard let isFinish = runningApp?.isFinishedLaunching,
                  let isActivate = runningApp?.isActive,
                  isFinish && isActivate else { continue }
            
            //Your code here

            break
        }
        
    }
    
}
```